# Ryanair visa/document check desk outside Europe

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu-citizens, ryanair

I am flying from Madrid (EU) to Morocco (non-EU) with Ryanair in a few days and I have an EU passport.
Do I need to go to visa/document check desk first?

Comment: What does it say in your booking T&C, and on the Ryanair website https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-gb/sections/360005048277-Travel-documentation?

Comment: They only say that i have to have a valid passport, but is not stated that i have to go and stamp my boarding pass at visa check desk.

Comment: Ryanair visa check is usually for non-EU passports, you don't hold a non-EU passport, so you're likely fine. Try to check in online and you'll be set

Comment: I will try this way and see what's up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I made it, I made online check-in and because I was citizen of EU I went directly to security. That was on Madrid-Marrakech.
When I departed from Marrakech I went to Ryanair check-in desk for a stamp on my boarding pass.